# How to customize Kibana dashboard?

Tags: iframe, customization, dashboard, kibana

I want to embed Kibana Dashboard in a HTML page using iframe. Also Discover and Settings should not be visible and on clicking Edit, chart should open in Visualize (like normally happens in Kibana)

I used 'embed=true' URL parameter. It hides menu bar but then it doesnt show the Edit option either.

How can I keep the Edit option and hide Discover and Settings?

Answer (score 3):

As of Kibana4, there is no such option till now. BTW, as a workaround you can pass some query string to the IFrame URL and based on the query string value, alter the kibana css to hide the edit buttons in your dashboard. But this is a bit complicate workaround.